# Verificar campos nulos ou vazios em uma entidade sem uso consecutivos de "if-else"

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, reflexão, serialização

Em uma integração entre sistemas há atualizações de dados de ambos os lados, em que se obtém o registro do Lado A e o registro do lado B. Se houver campos nulos em A e estes existirem em B então A é complementado com B o inverso também é verdadeiro, é como se fosse um *merge* entre os registros. Para resolver esta questão tentei duas formas que funcionaram, porém, pelo menos pra mim, está "gambiarrado".

#### 1ª Abordagem - Reflection

```
foreach (var propertyInfo in entidadeA.GetType().GetProperties(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance))
{
    var valor = propertyInfo.GetValue(entidadeA, null);
    camposNull.Add(nameof(propertyInfo.Name))
}
```

#### 2ª Abordagem - Verificação na instanciação da entidade

```
public class EntidadeA{
    private string _campoA {get; set;}
    public  string CampoA 
    {
      get { return _campoA; }
      set 
      { 
         _campoA = value;
         if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            camposNull.Add(nameof(CampoA))
      }
}
```

As entidades possuem mais de 20 campos, então meu objetivo é reduzir o máximo possível de `if-else`. Há alguma outra forma de se fazer isso? A segunda forma, caso a entidade seja usada em uma serialização para JSON ou XML poderia gerar problemas?

Comment: Você tem várias entidades diferentes? Cada uma com 20+ campos?

Comment: Não não, são somente algumas... se não me engano umas 2 ou 3...

Comment: A resposta resolveu o que estava em dúvida? Precisa que algo mais seja melhorado?

Answer (score 1):

Sempre há outra forma. A questão é saber se ela é adequada para necessidade atual e será para outras que possam surgir. Precisa fazer algo que seja conceitualmente correta.

Não vejo problemas na segunda forma. Uma serialização chamará o `get` e receberá o resultado.

Esse `camposNull` na classe está me parecendo gambiarra, não importa como ele é populado, mas pode ser correto, não tenho maiores informações para afirmar.

Mais estranho é uma propriedade que usa outra propriedade como campo. Pode, mas não sei se é a intenção.

Eu evitaria a reflexão, na verdade, sempre que puder. A performance é ruim e abre brechas para falhas no código até mesmo de segurança. Quando é necessário é uma ótima ferramenta, mas eu não abusaria. Em linguagens como C# se precisa automatizar algo prefiro geração de código ou fazer na mão.

Comment: `camposNull` é uma lista que contem os campos que são `null` na entidade, para fazer a verificação posterior se há campos nulos com, por exemplo, `if(entidadeA.camposNull.count > 0)`e assim poder "tratar" somente os campos que estão nulos a partir dos nomes que estão em `camposNull`

Comment: É, parece gambiarra. Esta informação é auxiliar e não faz parte do objeto.

Comment: Como seria uma conceitualmente correta a se implementar ?

Comment: Sem este campo :P Sem conhecer todo o problema é difícil dizer, mas talvez não deva ter estado, só obter a informação quando precisar, ou ter um objeto auxiliar para isto. Pode até ser correto, sei lá, só não me parece, parece um membro para facilitar um "trabalho sujo" e nçao necessidade do objeto.